# Highlight closest cell value in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a salary data table called **SalaryDataTbl** and to the right of it a selector where you can choose an employee in cell K2. L2 looks up their discipline and M2 looks up their salary.

[image: Salary Details]

Is there a way I can highlight the closest salary for their discipline in the SalaryDataTbl using an in cell function or data validation? Or is this going to require a VBA solution?

In the example in the image, for the salary of 3750 and discipline programming it should highlight cell G2.

**EDIT** New Sample Data exhibiting bug when salary is 65000 and using formula `=AND(ABS(D2-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP(D:I, 1)-$M$2)), $A2=$L$2)`

| Discipline | Level | Role | Min | Lower | Low-Mid | Mid-High | Higher | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Programming | Junior | Programmer | 1,000 | 2,000 | 3,000 | 4,000 | 5,000 | 6,000 |
| Programming | Mid-Level | Programmer | 7,000 | 8,000 | 9,000 | 10,000 | 11,000 | 12,000 |
| Programming | Senior | Programmer | 13,000 | 14,500 | 15,000 | 16,000 | 17,500 | 18,000 |
| Programming | Principal | Programmer | 19,000 | 20,500 | 21,000 | 22,000 | 23,000 | 24,000 |
| Programming | Director | Programmer | 25,000 | 26,000 | 27,000 | 28,000 | 29,000 | 30,000 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Design | Junior | Game Designer | 4,000 | 5,000 | 6,500 | 7,000 | 8,000 | 9,500 |
| Design | Mid-Level | Game Designer | 10,000 | 12,500 | 14,500 | 15,000 | 17,000 | 11,000 |
| Design | Senior | Game Designer | 10,000 | 12,500 | 15,000 | 16,000 | 17,000 | 18,000 |
| Design | Principal | Game Designer | 15,000 | 17,500 | 20,000 | 21,000 | 25,000 | 30,000 |
| Design | Director | Game Designer | 30,000 | 35,000 | 40,000 | 41,000 | 42,500 | 45,000 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlighting cells based on other cells' values is going to use Conditional formatting.
For this answer you'll need Excel 2021 or Excel for Office 365.
Select the range D2:I18, click 'Conditional Formatting' > 'New Rule' in home tab and change the setting to 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'.

The formula you need to use will be

```
=AND(ABS(D2-$M$2)=MIN(ABS(DROP($D:$I, 1)-$M$2)), $A2=$L$2)
```

You can then use the formatting settings to select whatever format you need to 'Highlight' relevant cells, e.g. change the fill to yellow.

Comment: I have Office 365 and when I add the new rule, set the colour fill to green and apply to =$D:$I it unfortunately doesn't do anything. Have I set something up wrong? On first setting it up it did lock my machine momentarily too while it was calculating.

Comment: By restricting the drop and the range to D2:I500 it doesn't lock up and works great

Comment: It would be able to work a lot quicker if you put the `MIN(ABS(DROP(D:I,1)-$M$2))` part in a separate cell and reference that in the formula - that's the part that takes the most to calculate, and in a conditional formula it's recalculating that for every cell it checks whereas if you put it in a separate cell, it will only calculate it once for the whole sheet.

Comment: If I have the same salary for multiple levels it will highlight both. If I were to pull the Level of the employee in to N2 would there be a way to include their level in the formula too?

Comment: Yes, the `$A2=$L$2` part is doing this for the discipline, you could add a similar condition for level.

Comment: Before I applied the Level addition I noticed a bug with the above formula. With certain salary values it doesn't highlight any cells. I created sample data exhibiting the issue and added it to the bottom of the question. When I use the salary 65000 it doesn't highlight any cells. In this sample case I'd expect it to highlight H4 and G5. If it incoporated the employee Level, and in this example it's a senior then it should highlight H4. Do you know what might be happening here?

Comment: Apologies, I've realised the D:I should be an absolute reference, editing the answer.

Comment: Again, that wouldn't be a problem if you have a separate cell (in my case I've used cell O2) containing the formula `=MIN(ABS(DROP(D:I, 1)-M2))`. Then, the conditional formatting can be applied to the whole of D:I and the format rule is just `=AND($A1=$L$2, ABS(D1-$M$2)=$O$2)` - it also calculates much quicker

Comment: I've applied the above to the same cell and changed the conditional formatting to the same but unfortunatelty it's still not highlighting any cell with the sample data.

Comment: Found the issue. I have more rows of data covering all disciplines, so more than the sample in the question above. If I remove all those rows it highlights the correct cell.

Comment: I've adjusted the sample data in the question above. When used with the latest formulas exhibits the bug.